# Running Multiple Node.js Versions in Tandem

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm working on two applications. The first one has been migrated to 4.2, the other one still needs to be migrated. So, I'm wondering... is there a way to run two different processes against two diff Node.js binaries? In this case, it would be 4.2 and 0.12.

Comment: yes.  should be as simple as `/path/to/nodev1 v1app.js` and `/path/to/nodev2 v2app.js`.  You'll run into node_modules issues if you try to develop on the same app w/ different node versions.  What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you use nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) you'll be able to do this easily.

Using `nvm` install both Node.js v4.2 and v0.12:

`nvm install 4.2`
`nvm install 0.12`

When you run `nvm use <version>`, nvm will set the Node.js version to `<version>` for just that terminal window/tab. So, in one terminal you can run `nvm use 4.2` then run your node.js application, and in another terminal window or tab run `nvm use 0.12` and run your node.js application that uses v0.12.

If you don't want that terminal window or tab to be scoped to a specific version of Node.js, you can use nvm to just run the server using `nvm run <version> <args>`. For example:

`nvm run 0.12 server.js`